# Angular 6 index in material table not working

Tags: html, angular, indexing, angular-material

I am having an issue when adding index to my table rows.
I have assigned index value like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index"> {{i+1}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

This solution is working on one table but on the second table it is returning NaN. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

On the second table I am using expandable rows so I have added multiTemplateDataRows attribute. Everything else is the same. I am using Material Design v7.11

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you are using `multiTemplateDataRows` property , you can't use index. Instead you have to use dataIndex or renderIndex.

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = renderIndex;">{{i+1}}</mat-cell>
```

Comment: Thannk you! Adding dataIndex instead of index solved my issue.

Comment: Amidst of coronavirus. I found this. Thanks my friend.